# How create call-graph using SPOON API

Tags: java, static-analysis, inria-spoon

If somebody used SPOON API can you give me some clue how to create call-graph and what I need to do it?

I think that I need to create some Processor like this:

```
public class InvocationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor<CtInvocation> {
    @Override
    public void process(CtInvocation element) {
        System.out.println(element.getActualTypeArguments());
    }
}
```

and then use Launcher for run analyse

```
public void getCallers(){

    final Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
    launcher.setArgs("-i D:\\IntelliJ_projects\\ComprehensionTool\\ -p comprehensionTool.analyse.processor.InvocationProcessor".split(" "));
    launcher.run();
}
```

but I am not sure about it... and I want to ask that do I need some special dependencies for using Launcher?

I assume that I am wrong because when I executed it this error  throw:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.<init>(Ljava/io/PrintWriter;Ljava/io/PrintWriter;ZLjava/util/Map;Lorg/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/CompilationProgress;)V
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBatchCompiler.<init>(JDTBatchCompiler.java:58)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBatchCompiler.<init>(JDTBatchCompiler.java:54)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.createBatchCompiler(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:352)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.createBatchCompiler(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:356)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.buildUnits(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:388)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.buildUnitsAndModel(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:372)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.buildSources(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:348)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.build(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:119)
    at spoon.support.compiler.jdt.JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.build(JDTBasedSpoonCompiler.java:102)
    at spoon.Launcher.buildModel(Launcher.java:700)
    at spoon.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:651)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a dependency to eclipse JDT, we are using this one:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.0.v20160516-2131</version>
</dependency>
```

The way you are launching Spoon seems good, however your processor will traverse the entire model and print invocation types: it does not follow the invocations. 
Creating a call-graph is not that easy: you have first to get the starting point (for example a method) and then to follow the invocation.

Getting the starting point is easy: have a look at [Spoon documentation](http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/filter.html), but then you need to manually traverse the call-graph to build it.

Answer (score 1):

I use recursion and start with a CtInvocation.

1. Find enclosing CtMethod.
2. Find N CtInvocations of CtMethod.
3. For Each CtInvocation in N recurse to step 1.

For better or worse, I used the GetParent() in a loop to find the CtMethod of the CtInvocation, seems like it would find the CtBody and then the CtMethod, but I think you need this for the case where the the CtInvocation is in other blocks ( if-statement ), while-loop, etc.

Comment: Hi, @Orsi, I quite agree with your idea to find the complete call sequence, so could you please provide some sample code here in your answer? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I would have to ask the student I am working with to see if she is willing to share the code, I will get back to you.

Comment: @Orsi, thanks a lot. Recently I have tried other program analysis tools, such as JSlice, Indus, Soot, etc, but failed to implement the call graph, looking forward to your reply :)